# ajax загрузка файлов - при размере выше 5мб - не отображает в $_FILES

Tags: php, ajax, ajax-load

Есть форма

```
<form action="">
    <input type="file" name="file" >
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Отправить"></input>
</form>
```

jQuery скрипт

```
$('input').on('change', function(e){
e.preventDefault();

var self    = $(this),
    file    = self[0].files[0];
    fd      = new FormData();

fd.append('file', file);

$.ajax({
    url: 'load.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: fd,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,

    xhr: function() {
        var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();

        if(myXhr.upload){
            myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',function(e){
                if(e.lengthComputable){
                    var max     = e.total;
                    var current = e.loaded;
                    console.log('Загружено: ' + current + ' из ' +max );
                } 
            }, false);
        }
        return myXhr;
    },

    success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
    },
});
});
```

load.php

```
 <?php 
      var_dump($_FILES);
```

Если я гружу картинку, весом 1-2мб - в консоле у меня вот что:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но, если я пытаюсь загрузить файл .mp4 весом 8мб, у меня пишет сколько загружено, но на сервере $_FILES - пустой...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему $_FILES пустой? Ограничения может какие-то проверить?...

Все дело - в весе файла. Если гружу размером выше 5МБ - то уже не показывает в $_FILES...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `php.ini` измените настройку `upload_max_filesize`.

Comment: Точно, только нужно было еще изменить и: post_max_size

Answer (score 0):

еще если nginx то изменить client_max_body_size

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]